# One thread read and one thread write, is std::deque safe?

Tags: c++, linux, volatile

Read thread calls `at(i)` function and write thread calls `push_back()` function, I get the error "out of range", Why?

Comment: I think that the variable of `size()` remains in each core's register? by using `volatile`, can we solve the problem for the certain situation that "one read one write"?

Comment: No, that's still UB.

Comment: write a self defined queue, define function `size()` by using `volatile` variable count.

Comment: You cannot use `volatile` for synchronization. Period. Writing a concurrent queue is not *that* easy.

Answer (score 3):

Calling any non-const member function on any standard library object is not thread-safe (unless a particular non-const function is documented otherwise). You need to synchronise access to the object to prevent data races and thus Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Using the "at" function for a deque is also pretty inefficient.